# It is correct to construct tree species-based rarefaction curves for birds?

Tags: ecology, statistics, data, biodiversity, community-ecology

If I register all the species of birds that uses sp1 tree, then, all the species of birds that use sp2 tree, and so on. With this dataset, I can made a rarefaction curve using "number of tree species" on X axis of the rarefaction graph, instead of using "number of samples"

Is this incorrect? Does anyone knows a paper that made something similar?